# Convert decimal to 10-digit number

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my c# application, I have a `decimal` value (`10.0`) that I need to insert into a database field (field type `BIGINT`).  The values currently in the db are all 10-digits long.

How can I convert my `10.0` `decimal` value to `1000000000`?

Thanks

Edit: This field is for the order amount being inserted into an order transactions table.  Not sure why they have 10-digit values in this field, but there's already millions of records in this table, all containing 10-digits.  So I'm just trying to keep my values the same.

Here's some basic add'l details.  In the below example, lets say I enter "10.00" into the txtOrderAmount textbox, I will need to convert this into "1000000000" to insert into the database:

### My c# application:

```
decimal orderAmount = 0;
orderAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOrderAmount.Text);
if(orderAmount > 0)
{
     ledger.InsertOrderTransaction(amount);
}
```

This calls InsertOrderTransaction, which then inserts into the database.

Some sample records from my database table, called "Ledger".  The sample values are for $50.00, $10.00, & $13.50 respectively:

### LedgerID  |  EntryDate  |  OrderID  |  Amount

2086      |  2-14-2014  |   1123    |  5000000000

2087      |  2-18-2014  |   1197    |  1000000000

2088      |  3-9-2014   |   8741    |  1350000000

Hope that helps.  Again, why the original developer did a 10-digit BIGINT here, I have no clue but I just want to keep my values the same as his.

Comment: Why do you want to convert 10 to 1000000000?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple multiplication?

Comment: why you are converting ?insert 1000000000 directly

Comment: If you need to store decimals, why not just change the field to a decimal? That seems a lot simpler than trying to do some strange conversion back and forth.

Comment: Maybe one way to do this would be to remove the dot and PadRight(10, '0')?

Comment: I agree.  It seems odd to store a 10-digit value for a dollar value.  Unless there's something I'm missing, it doesn't make sense to me.  But with that said, all of the records in this db & apps currently referencing it are setup to utilize it this way.  My app is just supposed to be a quick, small app to insert add'l records, so I just want to keep my values the same as what they're already inserting.

Comment: The reason you're getting all these bizarre suggestions is because no one understands what you have or what you're trying to do. Please give us examples of these `10.0 decimal` data, and of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What would a value greater than 99.99 look like on that table?

Comment: _So I'm just trying to keep my values the same._ Sounds like you want to ask someone for a spec before coding.

Comment: Add result of `select max(Amount), min(Amount) from <tablename>` sql query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help.  The problem with the answers was the calculation assumes the number will be between 10-99.

I tweaked it a little to be able to calculate any value:

```
int wholeVal = (int)amount;  //"amount" is a double & the original value from the textbox.  Counvert it to an int
int wholeValLength = wholeVal.ToString().Replace(",", "").Length;  //get the length of int
string calculation = "1";  //number to calculate begins with 1
for (int i = wholeValLength; i < 10; ++i)
{
     //add zeros to the calculation value
     calculation += "0";  
}
double dblCalculation = Convert.ToDouble(calculation);  
ledgerAmount = amount * dblCalculation;  //perform calculation
```

Comment: Be very, *very* careful when doing this. The convert back function is non-trivial (and actually impossible) when you remove the 10-99 requirement. How do you know what to divide by?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
decimal orderAmount = 0;
orderAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOrderAmount.Text);
if(orderAmount > 0)
{
     ledger.InsertOrderTransaction(amount * 100000000);
}
```

that's a simple multiplication an will treat the decimal as an integer if the `InsertOrderTransaction` method accepts an integer

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to just multiply:

```
Decimal myBigNumber = smallNumber * 100000000;
```

This comes with a major caveat: **Any numbers >= 100 will break** That is, they will be 11 digits long. Also, **numbers < 10 will break** because they will be 9 digits long.

*Because integers store no decimal-place information, there isn't an easy way to fix this without adding a field or converting to a floating-point type. Removing the the 10-99 requirement will make the conversion back to 10.0 impossible.*